# How do I recall a function and change some parameters?

Tags: python, function

First I have the definition:

```
architecture = FourPortArchitecture(height = height, width = width, mmi_model = mmi_model, wl0 = 1550e-9, length_wg = length_wg, neff = neff_wg, ng = ng_wg, length_wg_max_error=0, seed = seed).to(device)
```

In next part I want to use this architecture and change some values of the parameters. Should I write like this?

```
architecture = architecture(height = height, width = width, mmi_model = mmi_model, wl0 = 1550e-9, length_wg = length_wg, neff = neff_wg, ng = ng_wg, length_wg_max_error=0, seed = seed)
```

Comment: We don't know - what's `FourPortArchitecture` and does it implement `__call__`?

Comment: FourPortArchitecture is a function defined in another script.

Comment: And *does it* implement `__call__` to allow updating of an instance's values as you show here? We can't tell you that. Did you try it? Did it *work*? If not, give a [mre].